# Java - object oriented Table

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a problem during running my program. The result should be:

> null sczeka: ahau hau
>
> Ostatni pies ma na imie Azorek
>
> Szarik szczeka ahau hau
>
> Cywil Szczeka ahau hau
>
> Azorek Szczeka ahau hau

```
class Pies {
    String imie;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pies pies1 = new Pies();
        pies1.szczekaj();
        pies1.imie = "Azor";

        Pies[] mojePsy = new Pies[3];
        mojePsy[0] = new Pies();
        mojePsy[1] = new Pies();
        mojePsy[2] = pies1;


        mojePsy[0].imie = "Szarik";
        mojePsy[1].imie = "Cywil";

        System.out.print("Ostatni pies wabi sie");
        System.out.println(mojePsy[2].imie);

        int x = 0;
        while (x < mojePsy.length) {
            mojePsy[x].szczekaj();
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }

    public void szczekaj() {
        System.out.println(imie + " szczeka ahau hau");
    }
}
```

As a result, I got

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at pies.Pies.main(Pies.java:4)

and I completely do not have any idea why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). - could you please post the *complete* class, the *complete* error message and the compilation/ start command?

Comment: could you show the whole stack trace? what exception? I can execute this code, you maybe it's a missing import or something?

Comment: It worked for me. Are you using an IDE? Just go to the command line, compile Pies.java with javac, and then run it with "java Pies" and see if it works that way. If it does, then there's some issue with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's the explanation: https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/eclipse-compiler-surprises/

Eclipse generates .class files even for classes it can't compile, but all the methods of those classes do is throw an error with the message "Unresolved compilation problems: ..." That lets you run your program even if you have classes that don't compile, as long as you don't try to use any of their methods.

Cleaning and rebuilding your project should fix it.